# how to use intents in recyclerview items of navigation drawer to open a new activity fragment?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

My `activity` class is like following:

```
    /*ToolBar SetUp*/
    app_toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_header);
    setSupportActionBar(app_toolBar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    String TITLES[] = {"Home", "Search", "HalalRewards", "Contact Us", "User Guide", "F.A.Q", "Settings", "Share"};
    int ICONS[] = {R.drawable.ic_action_home, R.drawable.ic_search, R.drawable.ic_rewardsss, R.drawable.ic_contact, R.drawable.ic_uguide, R.drawable.ic_faq, R.drawable.ic_settings, R.drawable.ic_shareee};

    String NAME = "ESignature IT Solution";
    String EMAIL = "info@esignature.com.np";
    int PROFILE = R.drawable.intologo;

    /*Drawer SetUp*/
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size


    mAdapter = new DrawerAdapter(TITLES, ICONS, NAME, EMAIL, PROFILE);
    // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
    // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
    // and header view profile picture

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setOnClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager


    Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);        // Drawer object Assigned to the view
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, Drawer, app_toolBar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            // TO DO Execute code when Drawer view open
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            // TO DO Execute code when once Drawer is close
        }


    };
    Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();               // Finally we set the drawer toggle sync State

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// create fragmrnt loader funtion
// id get from adapter ....


/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        /*selectItem(position);*/ ///////////
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}

// Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        /*case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment();
            break;*/
        case 1:
            fragment = new SearchActivity();
            break;
         case 2:
            fragment = new HalalRewardsActivity();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new ContactUsFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new GuideFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new FaqFragment();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new SettingsFragment();
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment = new ShareFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();


        Drawer.closeDrawer(mRecyclerView);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
}
```

I am a new programmer. So proper help would be praiseworthy.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don"t write:

```
 mRecyclerView.setOnClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

because OnClick is not applicable in RecyclerView.
Instead use the following codes:

```
        final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

    });


    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

            if (child != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
                Drawer.closeDrawers();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The Item Clicked is: " + recyclerView.getChildPosition(child), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child) == 0) {

                } else if (recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child) == 5) {

                } else {
                    LoadFragmentView(recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        }
    });
```