# Nav drawer closed for a particular time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created a nav drawer using the recycler view concept. In my code there is a button on a action bar which, when clicked, opens a new list view like location selector. I want the nav drawer to be disabled for only that particular time till the list view opens.

Comment: add your code to get more idea

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341811/how-to-use-intents-in-recyclerview-items-of-navigation-drawer-to-open-a-new-acti

Comment: how to set nav drawer width in % in main java file